# Sharing folders across the internet

Tags: linux, windows, macos, network-shares

I have a software project me and a couple friends are working on, and I have all the files hosted on an Ubuntu server. On the server, everyone has their own user and their own home folder, and there's also a project folder in `/mnt/projects`. Currently, everything being messed with on the server is just being done over SSH, and but I would like to configure a way to access all the files through the native file browser. Initially, I went for a SMB share, but most ISPs (at least my own) block traffic on port 445. I was thinking WebDAV (either standalone or with nextcloud or something) next, but I don't know if it can do everything I need, either.

Here's my requirements for a protocol for this:

- Supported natively, or stupidly easy to get working in Windows Explorer, MacOS Finder, GNOME Files, KDE Dolphin
- When a user logs in, they should see their own `/home/$USER` folder, as well as `/mnt/projects`. If they have access to any additional folders over the network share, they should NOT have write access (ideally no read either).
- Protocol can be shared safely* over the internet, accessible from anywhere as long as they have the credentials to log in.

<sup>**I think everyone will define "safely" a little differently. Nothing crucial is being stored on the server. I just want something that requires credentials, has no guest access, and only gives those who are logged in access to the folders they have explicit permission to access. Encrypted data would also be a huge plus*.</sup>

What would be the best solution here, or is there even one? I feel like WebDAV might be the closest to what I want, but I cannot find any info on configuring the whole user folder thing.

Comment: "I went for a SMB share, but…" – VPN and *then* SMB or whatever.

Comment: "What would be the best solution here," - this is a product recommendation and is off-topic here.    I use Nextcloud for this problem.